# Calling one hook multiple times but running logic inside it only once for given render phase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have app where I have multiple calls to a hook, to simplify the example let's assume it looks like this:

```
const Test = () => {

  ...
  useTest();
  useTest();
  ....
}
```

and let's assume that `useTest` looks like that:

```
export default function useTest() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('test');
  })
}
```

how I can make the `console.log` to be run only once in given render/rerender phase no matter how many times this hook is called?

Comment: `useTest(); useTest();`  are totally independent, so if your expecting console.log once, then that's not going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dependency array on useEffect.

```
export default function useTest() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('test');
  },[]) // Run only once
}
```

```
export default function useTest() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('test');
  },[someVar]) // Run on first mount and every time someVar changes
}
```

Comment: Well it's not true - with an empty array this useEffect will be called as many times as the hook was called. Same with adding the variable to dependency array.

Comment: @mmmm  It shouldn't unless you have something broken... `[]` means it's only called on mount / dismount..  So unless you have something further up you render tree that's getting dis-mounted, a hook with `[]` will only get called once..

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-grass-qikhb here you have sandbox where it's basic react from the sandbox with this example. It's not working the way you described.

Comment: @mmmm  Your calling `useTest` twice, it's working totally as expected..   You maybe need to alter you question to try and explain what problem your trying to solve.  Why do you want to call useTest twice for example.   You might find thing like a context is what your after,... But it's unclear currently on what problem your trying to solve.

Comment: This is extremely simplified example for the sake of easier discussion. The concept is there, the question is actually quite clear. Application in itself is quite big and there are few places where given hook is called because it is returning some crucial things, but I don't want the logic to be run as many times as the hook is called. Can't explain it better.

Comment: @mmmm   Not sure how I can explain that multiple `useEffect`'s are totally independent.  If you want different `useEffect`s to be linked in some way a `useContext` is maybe what your after..  Can you not explain a simple example of what your trying to do, would be more than happy to knock up a snippet demonstrating `useContext`, but without more details it's hard to say if that's what your after.  If you can't explain better, I'm not sure we can help..

Comment: As @Keith said, useEffect should be used independently. If you give us a proper example of what you need, maybe a custom hook is not the solution for it.